# Не работает кликер: вместо числа кликов просто точка

Tags: python, tkinter

В месте, где должно показывать число нажатий, просто точка

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk



def click():
    global click
    click = click + 1
    output_label['text'] = (f'Счётчик: {click}')

    click = 0

    click = tk.Tk()
    click.geometry(f'500x500+200+200')
    click.title('Кликер')

    output_label = tk.Label(click, text=f'Счётчик:{click}', bg="black", fg="white", 
    font="Courier 20 bold")
    click_button = tk.Button(click, text='ЖМИ!', height="150", width="200",bg="white", 
    fg="black", font="Coureir 20 bold", command=click)

    output_label.pack()
    click_button.pack()
    click.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Правим отступы, разъединяем названия трех сущностей, названных одинаково (объекта окна, функции и переменной-счетчика), и все внезапно начинает работать как надо.

```
import tkinter as tk


def on_click():
    global click_count
    click_count = click_count + 1
    output_label['text'] = f'Счётчик: {click_count}'


click_count = 0

click = tk.Tk()
click.geometry('500x500+200+200')
click.title('Кликер')

output_label = tk.Label(click, text=f'Счётчик: {click_count}', bg="black", fg="white", 
                        font="Courier 20 bold")
click_button = tk.Button(click, text='ЖМИ!', height="150", width="200",bg="white", 
                         fg="black", font="Coureir 20 bold", command=on_click)

output_label.pack()
click_button.pack()
click.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Дополню, что такой код как у вас вообще упадёт с ошибкой при попытке вызвать функцию `click`:

```py
def click():
    global click
    click = click + 1

click()
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int'

Питон хранит все названия в одной куче - и переменные и функции, поэтому вот эта переменная `click`, которую вы объявили глобальной - она будет относиться к названию вашей функции. Попытка прибавить `1` к названию функции `click` окончится ошибкой.

А если вы после функции объявите переменную `click` вот так:

```py
def click():
    global click
    click = click + 1

click = 0
click()
```

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Тогда ошибка будет уже при попытке вызова функции `click`, потому что `click` теперь не указывает на функцию, а указывает на целочисленную переменную.

Не делайте так никогда, всегда давайте питоновским сущностям разные названия, чтобы они никогда не перекрывали друг друга.